# C# ILMerge Unable to cast object of type 'ClassY' to type 'ClassX'

Tags: c#, object, casting, ilmerge

Here's the situation:  I am using ILMerge to merge an assembly & all it's references into 1 .dll file using [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/jomo_fisher/archive/2006/03/05/544144.aspx) (`custom.dll`).  I have an application which dynamically loads this assembly at runtime (`program.exe`).  Both application & assembly use a common library (`common.dll`).  Abstract class `ClassX` is defined in `common.dll` whilst implementation `ClassY` is defined in `custom.dll`.  When `program.exe` tries to load ClassY from `custom.dll` it throws the exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'ClassY' to type 'ClassX'.

The code is like this, but `foo` is dynamically loaded rather than just a straight new ClassY();

```
object foo = new ClassY();
ClassX bar = (ClassX)foo;
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would do this?  `ClassY` definitely implements `ClassX`, all assembly/library versions are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the DLLs must be marked COM visible. Without it, the compiler could not resolved different assembly types -- even they are named the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the inner exception?  It's possible that since your ClassY is dynamically loaded that when you do the cast it's trying to load one of the pre-merged assemblies.  The inner exception would be "Unable to fin assembly '{you're pre-merged assembly name}'.